# Undefined pygame error during loading music

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

I have the following simple code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

pygame.mixer.music.load('menu.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)

is_running = True

while is_running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            is_running = False
```

It works fine when I compile it in the cmd. But when I used `pyinstaller` for convert this script to .exe file I was faced the undefined problem. When I launch the converted .exe file I get the following error from pygame:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load('menu.mp3')
pygame.error
[5208] Failed to execute script test
```

What does it happen for?

UPD: The .exe file and `menu.mp3` are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

what is your pyinstaller command? You need to tell which files are needed with the `--add-data` option.

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w --add-data='menu.mp3;.' test.py
```